# SSH connection to Ubuntu open SSH-server requires login on (physical) server via password first

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty, openssh

Heyho,

I have a kind of weird problem with an ubuntu server that runs open ssh-server.

Everything configuration wise is working except for one thing. I cannot connect via putty with my .ppk key to the server, right after it booted.
I get a "server refused our key". Since the thing is currently running in Virtual Box I still have access over the direct login. So I login with my user and my password and instantly log out again.

Now I can connect via putty and the .ook key. And I have no Idea why. Either I missed some explanation somewhere or I screwed up something somewhere with the configs. If anybody can point me in the right direction I'd be grateful!

sshd_config:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation no

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes no

RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
UseLogin yes

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no

AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

The key is in the decribed place and everything, and as said, I can connect just fine after logging in directly on the VM after a reboot, but no matter what I try I cannot get it to connect without that one login.

Comment: This is **not** a stackoverflow question - you're better asking on superuser. The two most common reasons for this happening are an encrypted home directory or a remotely mounted home directory where the mount happens through PAM, rather than through autofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered many times and is more suitable for [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/723908/429987).

In short, you have encrypted home folder (even with your `AuthorizedKeysFile`) and therefore the server can't authenticate you. One possibility is to move the authorized keys somewhere else (`AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys`) and decrypt your home folder upon login or just remove the encryption. [Official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Troubleshooting) describes it well.

Comment: Thank you very much, I spent one hour searching around for possible solutions, but never came across this, even once!